# Remove space from a path

Tags: c#, function, path

I have a string with a path that looks like this:

```
"Salle de bains / 01-Points d'eau / 01-01 Vasques"
```

Now I want to change this path to look like this:

```
"Salle de bains/01-Points d'eau/01-01 Vasques"
```

I already tried `Trim`, `Replace`, and `Substring` without success. I then tried this method:

```
private string UrlCreator(string dir)
{
    string dirFinish = dir;

    foreach(Char item in dirFinish)
    {
        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(item) && ((item-1).Equals('/') || (item+1).Equals('/')))
        {
            string charToChange = item.ToString();
            charToChange = "";
        }
        else { }
    }

    return dirFinish;
}
```

But this doesn't give me the desired result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use string when you run replace, not char.

Comment: Do you have only one space before and after the / or they could be more than one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [string replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8):

```cs
var myString = "Salle de bains / 01-Points d'eau / 01-01 Vasques";
var result = myString.Replace(" / ", "/");

// result -> "Salle de bains/01-Points d'eau/01-01 Vasques"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve that is combining [`Split(" / ")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) along with [`string.Join("/");`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) :

```
var input = "Salle de bains / 01-Points d'eau / 01-01 Vasques"; 
var output = string.Join("/", input.Split(" / ")); // Salle de bains/01-Points d'eau/ 01-01 Vasques
```

Performances are quite the same than using `Replace()`, however, `Replace()` is certainly *easier* to read and [Michael Hancock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59983317/8398549) is the way to go

---

You can use RegEx too if you don't know the number of spaces before and after the `/` :

```
var input = "Maison 42 / Salle de bains /01-Points d'eau/ 01-01 Vasques";

string pattern = @"\s*/\s*";
string replacement = "/";
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Output is

> Maison 42/Salle de bains/01-Points d'eau/01-01 Vasques

The pattern `\s*/\s*` does the following :

`\s*` searches for any number of white spaces

`/` followed by a forward slash

`\s*` followed by any number of white spaces

Comment: Unless there is more than one space before or after the /

Comment: @Steve indeed, I was typing a RegEx solution for that case

Answer (score 2):

Generalization: if you want to remove *arbitrary* number of *white spaces* before and after `/` you can use *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

// two spaces after 1st '/'; no spaces before 2nd '/' 
string source = "Salle de bains /  01-Points d'eau/ 01-01 Vasques";
string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\s*/\s*", "/"); 

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Salle de bains/01-Points d'eau/01-01 Vasques
```

Another possibility is *Linq*

```
using System.Linq;

...

string result = string.Join("/", source.Split('/').Select(item => item.Trim()));
```